# How to create TFS format which is generated by New List from Team Foundation Excel Add In?

Tags: c#, excel, tfs, excel-addins

I am trying to generate the format which comes from clicking the New List button in the Team Foundation Excel Add In. This format allows you to publish the Excel items directly to a specified TFS backlog.

When I generate the file it looks as follows:

[image: TFS add in generated format]

Since I want to generate this Excel sheet by code I am looking for a way to accomplish this by hand, without clicking the button. Unfortunately, when I just create the fields myself without formatting, the publish button is not available.

[image: TFS non-generated fields]

I want to have this Publish button available too.

The only difference I see are the colors and that the dropdownlists are read only. Are there any other differences?

How can I generate the sheet in a way so that the Publish button is available?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Why do you want to generate the list by code? Do you want to generate it by code and then paste it in Excel?

Comment: @Alica I am converting a JIRA backlog to TFS. JIRA is exported to XML-format and TFS backlog can be published to via Excel Team Foundation Addin. Now the XML is converted to an existing Excel, but it would be nicer if I could generate the whole sheet myself. And the nicest would be if I knew how the publishing to the backlog worked so the Excel step can be cut and we have the first working JIRA to TFS migration tool.

Comment: Do you have any coding experience? You could read the XML and create the TFS items using the TFS API.

Comment: Alicia the tool is now made in such a way that it reads the XML and places it in the Excel sheet. I guess the TFS API would have been cleaner. Did not know about it. I think it is quite valuable to make the tool so that it gets the Jira XML automatically and then uses the TFS API. Thanks for the advice!